# How to prevent Visio from printing all page tabs?

Tags: printing, microsoft-visio, tabs

I use Visio for single-line drawings and I frequently have several drawings in pages on a single Visio file. By default, Visio will print all pages unless the "Current Page" option is selected in the Print window. I would like the opposite, that is, I want Visio by default to print just the current page on display. Alternatively, is there a way to disable a page from being printed and not others? So, that if I just hit print, Visio will print everything, except those pages I disabled? I use Visio Premium 2010.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is convert pages you do NOT want to print to background pages (via Page Setup > Page Properties). The tab will be italic than. Only disadvantage is it moves to the right where all backgrounds resides.